# How to properly set a Cookie/Header for a SOAP client in PHP?

Tags: php, soap, soap-client, php-5.3

I am trying to enable xDebug support for a SOAP call following several topics I have found out there (see list at the end of this post) and this is what I have done so far:

```php
$this->_client_soap = new SoapClient(
    $this->ecase_wsdl,
    array(
        'trace'        => 1,
        'exceptions'   => true,
        'soap_version' => SOAP_1_1,
        'cache_wsdl'   => WSDL_CACHE_NONE
    )
);

// Xdebug Support
$xdebug_remote_address = $this->CI->config->item('xdebug_remote_address');
$xdebug_cookie         = $this->CI->config->item('xdebug_cookie');

if ($xdebug_remote_address && $xdebug_cookie) {
    $this->_client_soap->setCookie('X-Xdebug-Remote-Address', $xdebug_remote_address);
    $this->_client_soap->setCookie('Cookie', $xdebug_cookie);
}

$soap_string = $this->build_add_new_case_xml_string();

$ecase_response = $this->_client_soap->__doRequest(
    $soap_string,
    $this->ecase_wsdl,
    $this->service,
    SOAP_1_1
);
```

But I am getting the following `SoapFault` error message:

```
Function ("setCookie") is not a valid method for this service
```

What I am missing here? What is the right way to set a Cookie/Header? My PHP version is 5.3.3

Articles checked before:

- https://gist.github.com/Marko-M/10238b76c268ca9d47e5
- [Debugging a SOAP service using xDebug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20423317/debugging-a-soap-service-using-xdebug)
- http://www.practicalweb.co.uk/blog/2010/10/14/debugging-soap-with-xdebug-and-eclipse/
- [Nusoap set and get headers in both client and server side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34660955/nusoap-set-and-get-headers-in-both-client-and-server-side)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://php.net/manual/en/soapclient.setcookie.php

But seeing that the function is defined as magic, you're not supposed to call it directly.

Take care.

Comment: And its possible to access the cookies sent by SOAP server using $client->_cookies